# Is there a game that is both voxel and polygons?

Tags: voxels

Looking to see the difference between the two technologies in a game experience and not in experiments - is there a half-decent game out there that has two modes - polygons and voxel?

EDIT

Games like minecraft that voxels are exaggerated to make the game appear like a retro is not the intention. The comparison I want to make is for games that attempted to deliver realistic experience like outcast. In addition it would be best to see the same assets in both versions so not characters in polygons and landscape in voxels.

Comment: Voxels =/= cubes. We even had to change the tag description to reflect this some time ago

Comment: @Bálint you mean it's only to do with storage not rendering therefore won't affect gaming experience?

Comment: Yeah, basically. For example, lookup marching cubes

Comment: that makes sense in theory, i guess that could be the answer. However I'd still give a go to a game that has the two options if such exists

Comment: This question doesn't show much research effort. The most well-known voxel game of all time, Minecraft, is exactly that. The world is rendered using a voxel grid, and the characters are skinned polygon meshes (those meshes have cube-like shapes to fit the terrain's aesthetic, but look at them in motion and it's clear they're not locked in a common grid space)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking for a game recommendation; even if for research purposes, these questions are off-topic.

Comment: @DMGregory you're right, i'll clarify the question. Obviously i'm not after games like minecraft that try to look like LEGO or retro but those games like outcast that try to deliver realistic experience

Comment: Try to phrase it this way, if you can: what kind of help do you need in making *your own* game or mod? What kinds of considerations are relevant for the specific development choices you're facing? If this isn't about informing your own development process, then it might not be on-topic for this site, and you should try a discussion forum like GameDev.net or [chat] instead.

Comment: coming to think about it there must be a game that has been converted to win 7 / win 10, like what GOG are doing all the time, that used to be voxel now polygons. maybe that's the way?

Comment: *Most* voxel games are rendered by converting the surface to polygons. Is that what you're asking? It's hard to know what your end goal is here, or what it is you really want to know.